# Isomorphism and direct product of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need some clarification.

Consider these two groups: $\mathbb{Z}_{m}\times\mathbb{Z}_{k}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, where $mk=n$.

I know that if $m= 1$ or $k= 1$, then $\mathbb{Z}_{m}\times\mathbb{Z}_{k}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ are isomorphic.

And, on the other hand, I also know that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ (even though they have the same order).

So, what are the conditions under which these two groups are isomorphic?  (if any)

Is there any generalization that says that if $m\neq 1$ and $k\neq 1$ then $\mathbb{Z}_{m}\times\mathbb{Z}_{k}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ (where $mk=n$) are not isomorphic?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The necessary and sufficient condition for the groups to be isomorphic is that $m, k$ are coprime.

$$\mathbb Z_m\times \mathbb Z_k \cong \mathbb Z_{mk}\iff \gcd(m, k) = 1$$

Furthermore, if $\gcd(m, k) = 1$, it also holds that $\mathbb Z_{m}\times \mathbb Z_{k}$ is cyclic.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{Z}_{mk}$ always cyclic? ;)

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{mk}$ is always cyclic, by definition. I think you meant $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_k$ is cyclic iff $(k, m)=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. that was very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome, so.very.tired! (Get some sleep, dear tired one!) ;-)